What is the significance of lib, share and include? What to do with them?
I installed node.js using:
wget -q -nc --show-progress "https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest/node-v21.7.3-linux-arm64.tar.gz"

sudo tar -xvf node-v21.7.3-linux-arm64.tar.gz -C /usr/ --strip-components=1 --exclude='LICENSE' --exclude='CHANGELOG.md' --exclude='README.md'

node-v21.7.3-linux-arm64.tar.gz has four directories, namely lib, share, include and bin.
If I now want to place them somewhere in $HOME, do I need to copy
only the bin directory, or also lib, share, include? 
In the bin directory, is it said like go to ../lib, ../share, etc.,
so I do not have to include them (lib, share, include) in $PATH?
What is the significance of these directories (lib, share, include) and why do I need them?
